# How to count Number of refreshes of web page

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a web form of Asp.Net, in which I want JavaScript to count how many time i have refreshed the page.

Comment: try it by `cookies` in javascript

Comment: you want to calculate how many times every user refresh the page, or how many time the page refreshed generally?

Comment: how many times user refreshed the page... + i dont wanna use cookies isn't there anyother solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value in a [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/78c837bd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) using js or asp, or in a session value (for a single user) or in application value (for all the users), is not necessary javascript.

You have to put this code server side on page [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onload%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For all users:

```
Application["refresh_count"] =
 Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Application["refresh_count"]) + 1;
```

For a single user with session:

```
Session["refresh_count"] = Convert.ToInt64(Session["refresh_count"]) + 1;
```

OR

```
Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["refresh_count"] = Convert.ToInt64(Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["refresh_count"]) + 1;
Response.Cookies["UserSettings"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to count this per user ? Or for whole application ?

If you are doing for whole application you can use application variable in Global.asax on each page request . But that might get lost if your application recycles .

If you want to do for each user You can use server side sessions or cookies on clientside .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it on clientside just save (and retrieve) the information on `localstorage` every time  `load` event occurs

Answer (score 0):

You can save this in the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-EN/library/87069683%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery calling prepared address.
For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ".../countPageRefreshes.aspx",
  data: { page: "thisPageAddress" }
})
```

Then, in countPageRefreshes you can increase number of times, page was refreshed and save it somewhere.